# Exception handler in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, interceptor, custom-exceptions

I want to create an exception handler which will intercept all controllers in my project. Is that possible to do? Looks like I have to put a handler method in each controller. Thanks for your help. I have a spring controller that sends Json response. So if an exception happens I want to send an error response which can be controlled from one place.

Comment: what do you want the handler to do exactly?

Comment: @Bozho - question is updated.

Comment: I see. we had the same problem and chose to extend a base class that defines the handler (as suggested by gouki)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*(I found a way to implement it in Spring 3.1, this is described in the second part of this answer)*

See chapter [16.11 Handling exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) of Spring Reference

There are some more ways than using `@ExceptionHandler` (see [gouki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742324/exception-handler-in-spring-mvc/6742628#6742628))

- You could implement a [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) (*use the servlet not the portlet package*) - that is some kind of global @ExceptionHandler
- If you do not have a specific logic for the exception, but only specifc view then you could use the [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html), which is at least an implementation of the `HandlerExceptionResolver` where you can specify an Exception name pattern and the view (jsp) which is shown when the exception is thrown. For example:

  ```
  <bean
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
     p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
     <property name="exceptionMappings">
         <props>
             <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
             <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
             <prop key=".AccessDeniedException">accessDenied</prop>
          </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
  ```

---

In **Spring 3.2+** one can annotate a class with `@ControllerAdvice`, all `@ExceptionHandler` methods in this class work in a global way.

---

In **Spring 3.1** there is no `@ControllerAdvice`. But with a little hack one could have a similar feature.

The key is the understanding of the way `@ExceptionHandler` works. In Spring 3.1 there is a class [`ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.html). This class implements (with help of its superclasses) the interface [`HandlerExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) and is responsible invoking the `@ExceptionHandler` methods.

The `HandlerExceptionResolver` interface has only one Method:

```
ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response,
                              Object handler,
                              Exception ex);`.
```

When the request was handled by a Spring 3.x Controller Method, then this method (represented by `org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod`) is the `handler` parameter.

The `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` uses the `handler` (`HandlerMethod`) to obtain the Controller class and scan it for methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`. If one of this methods matches the exception (`ex`) then this methods get invoked in order to handle the exception. (else `null` get returned in order to signal that this exception resolver feels no responsible).

The first idea would be to implement an own `HandlerExceptionResolver` that behaves like `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, but instead of search for `@ExceptionHandler` in the controller class, it should search for them in one special bean. The drawback would be, that one has to (copy (or subclass `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`) and must) configure all nice message converters, argument resolvers and return value handlers by hand (the configuration of the real one and only `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` is done by spring automatically). So I came up with another idea:

Implement a simple `HandlerExceptionResolver` that "forwards" the exception to THE (already configured) `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, BUT with an modified `handler` which points to the bean that contains the global Exception handlers (I call them global, because they do the work for all controllers).

And this is the implementation: `GlobalMethodHandlerExeptionResolver`

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;


public class GlobalMethodHandlerExeptionResolver
             implements HandlerExceptionResolver, Ordered {

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -1; //
    }

    private ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver realExceptionResolver;

    private List<GlobalMethodExceptionResolverContainer> containers;

    @Autowired
    public GlobalMethodHandlerExeptionResolver(
            ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver realExceptionResolver,
            List<GlobalMethodExceptionResolverContainer> containers) {
        this.realExceptionResolver = realExceptionResolver;
        this.containers = containers;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
                                         HttpServletResponse response,
                                         Object handler,
                                         Exception ex) {              
        for (GlobalMethodExceptionResolverContainer container : this.containers) {    
            ModelAndView result = this.realExceptionResolver.resolveException(
                    request,
                    response,
                    handlerMethodPointingGlobalExceptionContainerBean(container),
                    ex);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
        // we feel not responsible
        return null;
    }


    protected HandlerMethod handlerMethodPointingGlobalExceptionContainerBean(
                               GlobalMethodExceptionResolverContainer container) {
        try {
            return new HandlerMethod(container,
                                     GlobalMethodExceptionResolverContainer.class.
                                          getMethod("fakeHanderMethod"));            
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }            
    }
}
```

The global Handler has to implement this interface (in order to get found and to implement the `fakeHanderMethod` used for the `handler`

```
public interface GlobalMethodExceptionResolverContainer {
    void fakeHanderMethod();
}
```

And example for an global Handler:

```
@Component
public class JsonGlobalExceptionResolver
             implements GlobalMethodExceptionResolverContainer {

    @Override
    public void fakeHanderMethod() {
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationErrorDto handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(
                MethodArgumentNotValidException validationException,
                Locale locale) {

         ...
         /* map validationException.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()
          * to ValidationErrorDto (custom class) */
         return validationErrorDto;
    }
}
```

BTW: You do not need to register the `GlobalMethodHandlerExeptionResolver` because spring automatically register all beans that implements `HandlerExceptionResolver` for exception resolvers. So a simple `<bean class="GlobalMethodHandlerExeptionResolver"/>` is enough.

Comment: Good answer. Can it be done with annotations? We have controllers that return Json response not a view.

Comment: @fastcodejava: I guess that there are no standard annotations. Anyway you can build you own.

Comment: The "Handling exceptions" chapter is 17.11 in the latest Spring reference. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Comment: @fastcodejava: If you are still interested: I have found a way how to made `@ExceptionHandler` methods responsible for controllers. - see my extended answer.

Comment: I used @ControllerAdvice. It does handle the exception and return the designated error page but the problem is that nothing is saved in the logs. Can you tell me how to enable logging for this?

Answer (score 15):

Since Spring 3.2 you can use [@ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation.
You can declare an [@ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) method within an @ControllerAdvice class 
in which case it handles exceptions from @RequestMapping methods  from **all** controllers.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value=IOException.class)
    public @ResponseBody String iOExceptionHandler(Exception ex){
        //
        //
    }

    // other exception handler methods
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 9):

An abstract class where you define the exception handlers will do. And then make your controllers inherit it.

Comment: Defining ExceptionHandler in abstract class do not work in my case (Spring 4.1.4).