# Return JSON on uncaught exceptions in Spring controllers

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, exception, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring controller annotated with `@RestController` and it is returning JSON. I also have a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` with `@ExceptionHandler`s related to some custom exceptions. I am using Tomcat to serve this RESTful API. I'd like to have any non-custom exception such as one coming from a 3rd party library or a NullPointerException be caught and returned with status 500 - Internal Server Error as JSON with a message instead of an HTML page showing the error.

If I use an `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` in the controller advice it takes over all of Spring exceptions like MissingPathVariableException.class, which is not ideal. I've tried extending Spring's ResponseEntityExceptionHandler but this class is not annotated with @ResponseBody so does not return JSON.

1. How do you return JSON for uncaught and unknown exceptions (ones you can't plan for) in a Spring RESTful API without influencing Spring's internals?
2. How can I turn off returning HTML entirely and ensure only JSON responses no matter whether the request has an exception or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For returning JSON on uncaught exceptions you can use this code:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@ControllerAdvice  
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private class JsonResponse {
        String message;

        public JsonResponse() {
        }

        public JsonResponse(String message) {
            super();
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }       
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)  
    public ResponseEntity<JsonResponse> handleException(Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<JsonResponse>(new JsonResponse(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

JSON result if exception is throwing:

```
{
    "message": "Something wrong!"
}
```

You can use this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) for more detailed information about Spring exception handling (with code examples).

Comment: How can we implement a similar class for Spring 3.1.4?

Comment: This topic can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742324/exception-handler-in-spring-mvc

Comment: This code was swallowing all the HTTPStatus codes from all my apis until I replaced the guts with
        `@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<JsonResponse> handleException(Exception e) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        ResponseStatus resp = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class);
        if (resp != null) {
            status = resp.code();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new JsonResponse(e.getMessage()), status);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

HttpEntity represents an HTTP request or response consists of headers and **body**.

```
// Only talks about body & headers, but doesn't talk about status code
public HttpEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers)
```

**ResponseEntity** extends HttpEntity but also adds a Http status code.

```
// i.e ResponseEntity = HttpEntity + StatusCode
public ResponseEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers, HttpStatus statusCode)
```

Hence used to **fully configure** the HTTP response.

If you have a look at constructor of **ResponseEntity** you will see first parameter as **body**, i.e exactly where you can **pass** the object you want as body of http response when exception arrives